# Extraction of Data after using one hot encoder technique

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, one-hot-encoding, mlp

I have a dataset which I have mobile names with their models. I want to basically extract those mobile names which have same model using AI Algorithm.

For models, I have used **One Hot Encoder** technique and I have dataset like this:

[image]

Afterwards, I implement MLP Classifier but unfortunately results are not coming as expected.

**Input Column:** Apple iPhone11

**Output Column:** Name

**MLP Implementation:**

```
clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(150,100,50), max_iter=300,activation = 
'relu',solver='adam',random_state=2).fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
clf = MLPClassifier(random_state=6, max_iter=200).fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
clf.predict(X_test)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Instead of MLP Classifier, can I use another algorithm for it.

Comment: I would simply use string matching on individual words for this. ML seems overkill and not all that suitable.